# unable to bootstrap ec2 ubuntu instance

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

Hi I am trying to bootstrap an ubuntu ec2 instance using knife command line tool, but when ever I run this command

```
knife ec2 server create -x ubuntu --region ap-southeast-1  -i ami-0cdf4965 -S key  --identity-file  ~/key.pem  -G default  -r 'recipe[apt],recipe[apache2],recipe[ntp],recipe[ruby]'
```

I knife throws out an error

```
ERROR: You did not provide a valid 'Image' value
```

and when ever I use -I ami-id it tell use -i instead of -I, but I can bootstrap an instance in us-east region but unable to do it in the ap-southeast region.

Kindly help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that Amazon Machine Images (AMIs) are region-specific.

According to [The Cloud Market](http://thecloudmarket.com/image/ami-0cdf4965--ubuntu-images-ebs-ubuntu-quantal-12-10-amd64-server-20130206#/definition) catalog of available AMIs, the AMI you're trying to launch - ami-0cdf4965 - only exists in the `us-east-1` region, which explains why you can launch an EC2 instance there but not in `ap-southeast-1`:

There are other AMIs for Ubuntu available in your desired region according to [this list](http://thecloudmarket.com/owner/099720109477--canonical) - e.g. `ami-64cf8236`. You could try launching one of them.

However if you really need to make that exact AMI available in another region you can use the AWS console to take a snapshot of an instance running that AMI in the `us-east-1` region, and copy the snapshot to the 'ap-southeast-1' region. [Here is Amazon's documentation on the AMI snapshot transfer between regions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-copy-snapshot.html). The process is very easy but will take some time to both take the snapshot and transfer it to the target region.

One word of caution is that you can be charged for snapshot storage and their transfer between regions at normal AWS usage rates.

Comment: I tried to bootstrap an instance using the ami-id you have specified but I am getting the same error also I tried to bootstrap an instance ami -id ami-10206d42 which actually belongs to ap-southeast-1 region as specified here http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/ FYI its a EBS based instance. Should I specify the ebs parameters in the command???

Comment: Easiest and fastest way to rule out an issue of regional availability would be to log into your AWS console and attempt to launch an instance there with your desired AMI. If it launches there then my answer is wrong.

Comment: Maybe you'll have better luck if you specify both region and availability zone - there are multiple AZs in asia-pacific, e.g. `
knife ec2 server create -I ami-b89842d1 -x ubuntu --region 'us-west-1' -Z 'us-west-1b'` only use your specific values

Comment: I was able to boot an instance with the AMI id ami-10206d42 using aws console but I am not able to bootstrap using knife, should I mention any about the EBS volume in the configuration command itself, I was able to boot an instance stored machine in US-EAST region last time

Comment: Now its saying key.pem not found in spite of giving the absolute path.